# Check if a class has a particular event?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way (maybe reflection?) to check if a class has a particular event?

For example, to check for different objects, one might do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.Count; i++)
{
    if (!(myObjects[i] is Control))
        continue;

    ((Control)(myObjects[i])).Validating += myValidationEvent;
}
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.Count; i++)
{
    if (!(myObjects[i].HasValidatingEvent))
        continue;

    ((Control)(myObjects[i])).Validating += myValidationEvent;
}
```

Where `HasValidatingEvent` checks if that object has a `Validating` event.

Comment: Well you can use reflection to find out if it has an event called `Validating`, but you'd need it to be of the right type (of delegate). Is there not some interface or base class that declares the event you want?

Comment: @JonSkeet myObjects list may contain controls (eg. TextBox) which do have a `Validating` event or  binding sources (which do not have). Does `Control` implement such an interface? it does have `CancelEventHandler`.

Comment: Simply check if the class is `Control` then and cast to `Control`, then you can access the validating event directly - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx - just like your first example. Why do you want to use reflection instead? What problems do you have with the first example?

Comment: Do you know exact event name to check ?

Comment: You could write extension method for this, but what's wrong with `myObjects[i] is Control` ?

Comment: @AlekseyL. I might have an object in the list which doesn't derive from `Control` but has a `Validating` event. @Sami The event name is `Validating`. Al

Comment: If you insist on using reflection, it is not too difficult: `foreach (var obj in myObjects) {
        if (obj == null)
        { continue; }
        var ei = obj.GetType().GetEvent("Validating");
        if (ei == null)
        { continue; }
        if (ei.EventHandlerType != typeof(CancelEventHandler))
        { continue; }
        ei.AddMethod.Invoke(obj, new[] { myValidationEvent, });
      }` However, it is probably not the best idea. You could also introduce an interface `IHasValidationg` with the event in it and have your types implement it. Then check `obj as IHasValidating`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use reflection to determine whether a class has a certain event, and create an extension method for `.HasEvent(string eventName)`. You would then still need additional reflection or type casting to assign an event handler to the object.

But suppose your list contains an object of a type that *also* has a `Validating` event, but it has a totally different meaning and/or a different signature - you don't just want any `Validating` event - you *specifically* want the `Control.Validating` event.

So regardless of whether such a property exists, casting to `Control` is the way to go. You can save a cast by the way by using:

```
Control control = myObjects[i] as Control;
if (control == null)
{
    continue;
}

control.Validating += myValidationEvent;
```

Comment: Another natural way is `foreach (var control in myObjects.OfType<Control>()) { control.Validating += myValidationEvent; }`.